# Dock has old MDM icons (?); how do I delete the old MDM icons from Dock

Tags: dock, mdm

Situation:
Mac laptop was part of a MacOS server profile managed MDM system, and it pushed some dock icons for that user XYZ.    Mac is now part of a new system, and uses the same users/uids.   When the user logs in their dock sees the same old list of icons from OS long ago along with new ones.

Actions:

- Tried to remove dock plist files  - but those are local not global so no effect
- Tried defaults write options listed elsewhere - again local not global
- Verified and made sure that the MDM profiles were removed from the old system - no effect
- Tried the normal delete options, but the OPTION menu comes up and it blank (including the obvious drag and drag with option/ctrl)
- Verified this happens to multiple users on the computer
- Looked in /var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/  but the "Store" is a secret hidden-ish file and likely clobbering that too much would render my current LDAP/MDM borked.

Request:
Anyone have an idea on where to try next?  Is there a way to reset the Dock for all the users and remove the global pushing of the old icons?  Do I need to delete the user and re-create through the new MDM/LDAP system?  Where do those MDM pushed dock settings come from now that the MDM system is gone....

Note:  Contacts icon which is gone from OS; Options menu is empty; and the list of icons in the pictures.
[image: Options Empty]
[image: Old Contacts App]
[image: Entire Dock w/ old stuff from Global MDM]

Comment: Have you tried just dragging them up out of the dock? You should get the 'ghost' with Remove… https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMEnk.jpg [I don't have a ? to use as an example]

Comment: Oh yeah - tried all the normal Dock management techniques - clarified that in the original post.

Comment: I discovered the problem. The /Library/Managed Preferences/ is a location where .plist files are that merge with your standard preferences. These can sometimes be left over from a previous MDM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tried all of the other documented or recommended solutions for fixing the dock with frozen icons, icons you can't delete, or icons with ? that you can't delete or remove, then make sure you try

```
/Library/Managed\ Preferences
```

There you should find some .plist files and resources from MDM or profile management which may be your source of ghosts.